# Publishing ASP.NET web application using High Charts

Tags: asp.net, highcharts

I am trying to publish my site, and have recently added in High Chart. The site published fine, prior but now i get this error message:

Copying file Highcharts-3.0.5\exporting-server\java\highcharts-export\highcharts-export- convert\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\converter\SVGConverterException.java to C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\xxx-1308748315\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\Highcharts-3.0.5\exporting-server\java\highcharts-export\highcharts-export-convert\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\converter\SVGConverterException.java failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters

Any ideas what is causing this, i fail to find anything on google?

Comment: Can u put both Highcharts and the project to same folder and then proceed.

Comment: All folders are part of the Website

Comment: It looks like a problem with paths, and .asp limation, not highcharts